# Generating diagrams in Pharo/Squeak Smalltalk

Tags: uml, smalltalk, class-diagram, squeak, pharo

I'm having trouble understanding big code libraries in Pharo and Squeak, is there is a typical template script to generate a static class relationship diagram (not necessarily UML) and a dynamic object relationship diagram in Pharo or Squeak without need to install all the Moose suite? Someone knows how to install just the specifc packages for rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A large Smalltalk system is complex and takes a lot of time to understand. No tooling is going to make it *easy*. On the other hand, all the information is in the system and easily accessible using a workspace and the inspectors and browsers.

1. There is of course the Moose one-click image. That is not complex to install and consists of a recent Pharo image. Open up a Mondrian Easel and take a look in examples.
2. There was a [Google Summer of Code project](http://forum.world.st/Introducing-smallUML-a-little-project-to-help-us-document-td2331341.html) to create class diagrams for packages to help you document your code.
3. An UML class view on a Smalltalk system is not often a useful view. The number of methods of classes deep in the hierarchy tends to be rather high. Understanding the system comes from learning to use all the different provided browsers and viewers. You know how to use implementers, senders, hierarchy, versions, and print-do-inspect-explore?
4. You can easily create your own browsers using Glamour, a part of MOOSE.
5. I've generated UML diagrams using graphviz.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen graphviz for generating dependencies diagrams but not for class based diagramming. Is there a specific binding/package for drawing UML-like diagrams with graphviz?

Comment: No, just a generic Graphviz binding.

Answer (score 2):

[There seems to be some `UMLDesignExtractor`, described in a thesis](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/projects/Schw00a.pdf), running within [Moose](http://www.moosetechnology.org/).

Comment: Interesting, but I cannot download the source code of UMLDesignExtractor, it is possible to use it without installing Moose?